# Error with proguard, glide 3.6.1 and gradle 1.3.1

Tags: android, gradle, proguard, minify, android-glide

When using proguard with minifyEnabled true I get warning during assembleRelease and my application does not load most of the images that I use glide for loading.

In debug release and if I set minifyEnabled false everything works fine. 
Can you please help?

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xxxxxx"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 17
    versionName "1.20151021"
}

allprojects {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation"
    }
}
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def appName
    //Check if an applicationName property is supplied; if not use the name of the parent project.
    if (project.hasProperty("applicationName")) {
        appName = applicationName
    } else {
        appName = parent.name
    }

    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def newApkName
        //If there's no ZipAlign task it means that our artifact will be unaligned and we need to mark it as such.
        if (output.zipAlign) {
            newApkName = "${appName}-${output.baseName}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
        } else {
            newApkName = "${appName}-${output.baseName}-${variant.versionName}-unaligned.apk"
        }
        output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, newApkName)
    }
}

signingConfigs {
    free {
        storeFile file('xxxxxx')
        storePassword "$System.env.KEYSTORE_PASSWORD"
        keyAlias "xxxxx"
        keyPassword "$System.env.KEYSTORE_PASSWORD"
    }
    pro {
        storeFile file('xxxx')
        storePassword "$System.env.KEYSTORE_PASSWORD"
        keyAlias "xxxxxx"
        keyPassword "$System.env.KEYSTORE_PASSWORD"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        // signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

productFlavors {
    free {
        applicationId "com.xxxxxx"
        buildConfigField 'Boolean', 'IS_APP_PRO', 'false'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.free
    }
    pro {
        applicationId "com.xxxxxxx"
        buildConfigField 'Boolean', 'IS_APP_PRO', 'true'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.pro
    }
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
}
```

**proguard-rules.pro**

```
-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public enum         com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.ImageHeaderParser$** {
    **[] $VALUES;
    public *;
}
```

**Warnings during assembleRelease:**

```
Executing tasks: [assembleRelease]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preFreeReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkFreeReleaseManifest
:app:preFreeDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preProDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preProReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareFreeReleaseDependencies
:app:compileFreeReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileFreeReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateFreeReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateFreeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeFreeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateFreeReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateFreeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeFreeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processFreeReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processFreeReleaseResources
:app:generateFreeReleaseSources
:app:processFreeReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileFreeReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileFreeReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileFreeReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:lintVitalFreeRelease
Unexpected failure during lint analysis of ArticlesRecyclerViewAdapter.java (this is a bug in lint or one of the libraries it depends on)
TypeSystem.getUnannotatedType(TypeSystem.java:180)->TypeSystem.getParameterizedType(TypeSystem.java:238)->TypeSystem.getParameterizedType(TypeSystem.java:261)->LookupEnvironment.createParameterizedType(LookupEnvironment.java:949)
Unexpected failure during lint analysis of CategoriesRecyclerViewAdapter.java (this is a bug in lint or one of the libraries it depends on)
TypeSystem.getUnannotatedType(TypeSystem.java:180)->TypeSystem.getParameterizedType(TypeSystem.java:238)->TypeSystem.getParameterizedType(TypeSystem.java:261)->LookupEnvironment.createParameterizedType(LookupEnvironment.java:949)
Unexpected failure during lint analysis of ArticleDetailActivity.java (this is a bug in lint or one of the libraries it depends on)
TypeSystem.getUnannotatedType(TypeSystem.java:180)->TypeSystem.getParameterizedType(TypeSystem.java:238)->TypeSystem.getParameterizedType(TypeSystem.java:261)->LookupEnvironment.createParameterizedType(LookupEnvironment.java:949)
Unexpected failure during lint analysis of SplashActivity.java (this is a bug in lint or one of the libraries it depends on)
TypeSystem.getUnannotatedType(TypeSystem.java:180)->TypeSystem.getParameterizedType(TypeSystem.java:238)->TypeSystem.getParameterizedType(TypeSystem.java:261)->LookupEnvironment.createParameterizedType(LookupEnvironment.java:949)

:app:proguardFreeRelease
Note: there were 7 duplicate class definitions.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass)
:app:dexFreeRelease
:app:shrinkFreeReleaseResources
Removed unused resources: Binary resource data reduced from 16682KB to 3190KB: Removed 80%
Note: If necessary, you can disable resource shrinking by adding
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources false
        }
    }
}
:app:validateFreeSigning
:app:packageFreeRelease
:app:zipalignFreeRelease
:app:assembleFreeRelease
:app:checkProReleaseManifest
:app:prepareProReleaseDependencies
:app:compileProReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileProReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateProReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateProReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeProReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateProReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateProReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeProReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processProReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processProReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateProReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processProReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileProReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileProReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileProReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:lintVitalProRelease
Unexpected failure during lint analysis of ArticlesRecyclerViewAdapter.java (this is a bug in lint or one of the libraries it depends on)
TypeSystem.getUnannotatedType(TypeSystem.java:180)->TypeSystem.getParameterizedType(TypeSystem.java:238)->TypeSystem.getParameterizedType(TypeSystem.java:261)->LookupEnvironment.createParameterizedType(LookupEnvironment.java:949)
Unexpected failure during lint analysis of CategoriesRecyclerViewAdapter.java (this is a bug in lint or one of the libraries it depends on)
TypeSystem.getUnannotatedType(TypeSystem.java:180)->TypeSystem.getParameterizedType(TypeSystem.java:238)->TypeSystem.getParameterizedType(TypeSystem.java:261)->LookupEnvironment.createParameterizedType(LookupEnvironment.java:949)
Unexpected failure during lint analysis of ArticleDetailActivity.java (this is a bug in lint or one of the libraries it depends on)
TypeSystem.getUnannotatedType(TypeSystem.java:180)->TypeSystem.getParameterizedType(TypeSystem.java:238)->TypeSystem.getParameterizedType(TypeSystem.java:261)->LookupEnvironment.createParameterizedType(LookupEnvironment.java:949)
Unexpected failure during lint analysis of SplashActivity.java (this is a bug in lint or one of the libraries it depends on)
TypeSystem.getUnannotatedType(TypeSystem.java:180)->TypeSystem.getParameterizedType(TypeSystem.java:238)->TypeSystem.getParameterizedType(TypeSystem.java:261)->LookupEnvironment.createParameterizedType(LookupEnvironment.java:949)

:app:proguardProRelease
Note: there were 7 duplicate class definitions.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass)
:app:dexProRelease
:app:shrinkProReleaseResources
Removed unused resources: Binary resource data reduced from 16682KB to 3190KB: Removed 80%
:app:validateProSigning
:app:packageProRelease
:app:zipalignProRelease
:app:assembleProRelease
:app:assembleRelease

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 29.188 secs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. The problem was that my images were in the drawable folder and shrinkResources was removing them because I wasn't using them hardcoded in the code. I disabled shrinkResources and downgraded to gradle 1.3.0 and now everything works fine.

Comment: Use this to keep your resources: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-shrinking